# rake: uninitialized constant in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, whenever

I have some custom classes/modules defined under `/app/lib`.

I have a Rake task, via whenever, that tries to load the environment then execute one of the class methods.

Here's an example of the rake task:

```
namespace :box do
  task :fetch => :environment do
  BoxInterface::Tasc::Fetcher.fetch
  end
end
```

If I run `BoxInterface::Tasc::Fetcher.fetch` from the Rails console, it works fine.

If I run `bundle exec rake 'box:fetch'` I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant BoxInterface::Tasc
```

The file structure under lib is:

```
/app/lib/box_interface/tasc/fetcher.rb
```

The odd thing here is that we have a staging server that this code works fine under.  Does this have something to do with the environment? I am unsure how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the folders in your lib directory to your autoload path in your `application.rb` file? You might have to do that if you're using Rails 3.0 or greater.
Try adding this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/box_interface/tasc)
```

inside of your class definition (`class Application < Rails::Application`) in the `application.rb` file.

Comment: discovered it was environment. my config/environments/production.rb file had config.threadsafe!   enabled. I commented out this line and now it works!.  I did consider add the config.autoload_paths.  but I thought loading the environment (e.g. => :environment do) would handle it